# How can I add hover to any CTA using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Start Order button on [this website](https://order.subway.com/Stores/Find.aspx?pid=1&intcmp=ordersubwaycom:owned:order:flavor:fwh-flavor-w5-2017:0:im:0:order-now:mrq:v1&segment_code=0) which when hovers changes the image. I want to replicate the same functionality to Use current location button which is next to Start order button.
Currently, I am using this code to make use current location as a button, but I want hover as well.

```js
jQuery("#divSearchLocation #btnGeolocation").css({
  "border": "1px solid #b5b5b5",
  "border-radius": "100px",
  "padding": "8px",
  "background": "#e1e1e1",
  "box-shadow": "0 1px 2px #000",
  "margin-top": "6px"
});
jQuery(".realContent").css("color", "#353535");
```

Comment: Please take care to format your questions properly - this was an unreadable mess before I edited it.

Comment: Any specific reason to use `CSS` within `JavaScript` when proper selectors (e.g. `#divSearchLocation #btnGeolocation`) are available?

Comment: I cant find start order button

Comment: Thanks for correcting it, though can you please provide any relevant answer to this question.

Comment: @AlaaMh... It is next to the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can (and maybe must) do it with css as it is made for this.
you need first to find your div and use the :hover method

You can put this in your html :

```
<style>
  #btnGeolocation:hover {
    color :red; //just add whatever you want, like background-image
  }
</style>
```

and start creating a personal stylesheet in your 'Styles' folder if you know how to

Comment: Not able to do it... I am having this div ID.

#divStoreTextLinksMobile

Comment: no, your `#divStoreTextLinksMobile` contain `#btnGeolocation` so you need to set your style on the #btnGeolocation div.